# How to slice a disc, and yet keep the pieces locked in together?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I have a bit of a complicated challenge

Could some one show how I can slice 22 perfect slices out of disc with the primary diameter line starting at the top like in this image like this

https://www.biblewheel.com//images/BibleWheel_Color_550.gif

The first slice I am referring to is the line between the 1st and 22nd spoke, which then goes through in between the 11th and 12th spokes

I have to cut them, however, keep them altogether so I can move the disc around when needed.

Comment: Remember to accept an answer if it is the right one so your question is removed from the "Unanswered" section of this site.

Comment: Don't post your email publicly unless you want spam. Answers to questions post at stack exchange stay at stack exchange not users personal emails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start blender and delete the default cube.

Press <kbd>Num Pad 7</kbd> for top view. Your scene should look like this:

[image]

Now press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select *Mesh ‣ Single Vert ‣ Add Single Vert*

[image]

Now press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode. Press <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> then <kbd>1</kbd> to extrude the vertex up on the "y" axis.

[image]

Now set *Pivot Point* to *3d Cursor*.

[image]

Now press <kbd>A</kbd> until both your vertices are selected, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to spin your mesh, and finally <kbd>F6</kbd> to bring up the operator settings. Copy the values below (22 steps and 360 degree angle).

[image]

Now press <kbd>A</kbd> until until all vertices are selected, then go to *Tool Shelf ‣ Tools ‣ Mesh Tools ‣ Remove:* and click *Remove Doubles*.

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and select "Face"

[image]

Now select a face and press <kbd>Y</kbd> to separate.

[image]

Do that for all the faces and you are done.

[image]

I hope this helps you.

[image]

Comment: 'kbd' formatting for individual keyboard keys please. E.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Also, code formatting (`) tends to be better just for code - italics might work better here.

Comment: @RayMairlot Oh thanks, I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: It would be quicker to select all (in Edit Mode) and press "P" > Loose Parts.

Comment: @Dontwalk No because:
A) He wanted them all in the same object, and
B) In order to use the _Loose Parts_ separator the parts have to be loose (disconnected) to begin with.

Comment: @TechTornado the add single vert is from the *Add Mesh Extra Objects* addon, which isn't enabled by default.

Comment: Hey thanks for showing me this. my next problem... When I select "Face" and hit Y nothing happens. I have 22 edges, however, the circle is hollow

Comment: @SalvatoreFanara Something did happen. If you select that face again and press "G" you will notice that it moves separately from the rest of the object as shown in the last picture of my post. Now that you've separated one face you can go through and separate the others, or use the edge ripping (select all the inner edges and press "V").

Comment: Thank you for your help techtornado. I am not able to get what you are showing me. The object I have is just an outline, not solid (in grey) and nothing seems to be responding to the commands you have given me. I am using version 2.79, don't know if mentioning that changes things...

Comment: @SalvatoreFanara Maybe you should add a link to your blend file [(You can upload it here)](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to your question. Seeing the file may give me a better idea of how to help you.

Comment: here you go...

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5022" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5022/)

Comment: In the meantime, I may try Robin Betts method

Comment: @SalvatoreFanara Go for it. I'll see what I can do, and Robin's method should work very well too.

Comment: Also I found the problem in your blend file: You moved your center vertex before you spun it instead of extruding it and then spinning it. You are welcome to download and use my example blend file for your project if you want because it is already finished.

Comment: Oh! I wouldn't have known what I was doing haha! I must tell you just this little bit about myself.... I am brand new to blender and haven't a clue what I am doing yet with every move I make. I'm gonna have to explore blender from now on and in the coming months when I can fit some time in between weekly commitments I should eventually get the jist of it.

I hope you'll be always around to help     :D

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> Order up a Mesh>Circle
- In the Tool Region, set 'Vertices' to say, 22*8 .. (this will give you 8 vertices per segment, to maintain the curvature of the arcs).. and the 'Fill Type' to Triangle Fan.

[image]

(It might be better to texture your object now, while it's intact, but this question isn't about texturing)

- In Edit mode, select the North radius, and another, 8 segments away.

[image]

- If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> repeatedly, now, every 8th radius will be selected.

[image]

- Now Rip the selected edges ( <kbd>V</kbd>)
- With all faces selected, Separate (<kbd>P</kbd>>By Loose Parts) the circle into 22 objects
- At the world origin, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> create an Empty
- With all the segments selected, and the Empty selected last, (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > Object) set the empty as parent to the segments.

[image]

Now, by transforming the Empty, the segments will move as one. You can move the segments independently .. if you want to return a segment to the circle, just set its Transforms to 0.